# What should I do if I delete the boot folder

Tags: boot, live-usb, grubrescue

I change the partion of the system with Geparted in the liveusb, ignoring some warning.  Then reboot, 'grub>' appears but I can not find the boot or grub folder anymore. Afterward, I reinstall ubuntu and I pay a high price. Then I want to learn a better way rather than reinstall when one comes into this case.

Answer (score 1):

One option you could try would be to use a liveCD to restore your /boot directory, however this probably isn't the best idea.

Realistically, I'd save any important files from the disk and reinstall - the /boot folder contains various kernel versions and other important stuff, and if you incorrectly 'repair' it, you could cause even more issues.

Comment: Thanks! yeah, that is what I did, but it takes heavy price too. So I search for a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

In case you had not written anything on your hard drive you may be able to recover overwritten partitions using [testdisk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/testdisk) [image: Install testdisk]:

> **Recovering Partition Tables**
>   If you accidentally overwrite your partition table, there is a chance that you might be able to recover it.
>   The testdisk application is designed to help recover lost partitions. For more information about testdisk, see http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk. <sup>Gparted help</sup>

Please follow the concise [step by step guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) from the makers of TestDisk to do so.

Comment: Thanks! It's very helpful. But I can not come into my system before  I reinstall it.

Comment: TestDisk must be run from a live system.

Comment: what about a livecd or liveusb?

Answer (score 0):

What do you do if you break/lose/delete Grub? [Reinstall it!](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Reinstalling_GRUB_2) You'll need a LiveCD and the willingness to read some instructions.

There are many alternatives but BootRepair works well and is fairly simple and when that's not enough the chroot method will let you do anything else (and is a very handy technique to know about for future issues).

Comment: `/boot` also contains kernels; reinstalling GRUB2 will not restore them--they must also be reinstalled (or their files copied back, if there is a backup).

Comment: `sudo update-initramfs` may help here but you'll need to follow the chroot method (as above) until just **before** you `grub-install` (so just after step 9). Verify that /boot has been partially restored and then carry on with the grub reinstallation.